# Get row from one table, plus COUNT from a related table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to build an SQL query where I grab one table's information (`WHERE shops.shop_domain = X`) along with the COUNT of the customers table `WHERE customers.product_id = 4242451`.

The shops table DOES NOT have `product.id` in it, but the customers table DOES HAVE the `shop_domain` in it, hence my attempt to do some sort of join.

I essentially want to return the following:

- shops.id
- shops.name
- shops.shop_domain
- *COUNT OF CUSTOMERS WHERE customers.product_id = '4242451'*

Here is my not so lovely attempt at the query. 
I think I have the idea right (maybe...) but I can't wrap my head around building this query.

```
SELECT shops.id, shops.name, shops.shop_domain, COUNT(customers.customer_id) 
FROM shops 
LEFT JOIN customers ON shops.shop_domain = customers.shop_domain 
WHERE shops.shop_domain = 'myshop.com' AND 
      customers.product_id = '4242451' 
GROUP BY shops.shop_id
```

Relevant database schemas:

```
shops:
id, name, shop_domain

customers: 
id, name, product_id, shop_domain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  The condition on `customers` needs to go in the `ON` clause, because this is a `LEFT JOIN` and `customers` is the second table:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.shop_domain, COUNT(c.customer_id)
FROM shops s LEFT JOIN
     customers c
     ON s.shop_domain = c.shop_domain AND c.product_id = '4242451'
WHERE s.shop_domain = 'myshop.com'
GROUP BY s.id, s.name, s.shop_domain;
```

I am also inclined to include all three columns in the `GROUP BY`, although Postgres (and ANSI/ISO standards) are happy with just `id` if it is declared as the primary key in the table.

Comment: Wow. That was incredibly quick. I just threw this in and I believe it works perfectly.... Give me a few minutes to just run a test through this. 

Thanks so much Gordon.

Comment: You rock. Thanks so much Gordon, really appreciate it. Have a great day.

Comment: Postgres is only happy with the PK in this case. `UNIQUE` is not enough (short of fully implementing the standard).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Thank you for the clarifying.  I see now that the documentation not only says "functional dependency" but also gives "primary key" as the definition.

Answer (score 1):

A **correlated subquery** should be substantially cheaper (and simpler) for the purpose:

```
SELECT id, name, shop_domain
     , (SELECT count(*)
        FROM   customers
        WHERE  shop_domain = s.shop_domain
        AND    product_id = 4242451) AS special_count
FROM   shops s
WHERE  shop_domain = 'myshop.com';
```

This way you only need to aggregate in the subquery, and need not worry about undesired effects on the outer query.

Assuming `product_id` is a [*numeric* data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html), so I use a [numeric literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) (`4242451`) instead of a string literal `'4242451'` - which might cause problems otherwise.